# How to show all x-axis values in a graph on Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I got a barchart that shows me the exact information i want, but i got a little problem on the view of the chart. It only shows the 1st field and not all the field on the x-axis. In this case, shows names.

This is my bean:

```
public void graficar(){
    barra = new BarChartModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
        ChartSeries serie = new BarChartSeries();
        serie.setLabel(lista.get(i).getNombres());
        serie.set(lista.get(i).getNombres(), lista.get(i).getCantidad());
        barra.addSeries(serie);
    }
```

And this is the part where i give the data for the axes.

```
barra.setTitle("Cantidad de prospectos asignados a ejecutivos");
    barra.setLegendPosition("ne");

    Axis xAxis = barra.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setLabel("Ejecutivo");

    Axis yAxis = barra.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Prospectos");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(10);
```

This is my xhtml:

```
<h:form>
            <h:panelGrid id="panel" style="alignment-adjust: middle">
                <p:chart type="bar" model="#{dashboardBean.barra}"
                         class="center-block"
                         rendered="#{dashboardBean.barra != null}"
                         responsive="true"/>
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
```

Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, finds out that i must put outside the for the addseries

```
ChartSeries serie = new BarChartSeries();

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

        serie.setLabel(lista.get(i).getNombres());
        serie.set(lista.get(i).getNombres(), lista.get(i).getCantidad());
    }
barra.addSeries(serie);
```